# Docker for Windows not working

Tags: docker

I've installed Docker toolbox now and I get the error for everything:

```
Get http://127.0.0.1:2375/v1.20/version: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2375: ConnectExtcp: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it..
* Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
* Is your docker daemon up and running?
```

`docker version` output:

```
Client:
 Version:      1.8.1
 API version:  1.20
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   d12ea79
 Built:        Thu Aug 13 02:49:29 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
Get http://127.0.0.1:2375/v1.20/version: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2375: ConnectEx tcp: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it..
* Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
* Is your docker daemon up and running?
```

But the VM is running under VirtualBox. I have searched everywhere but can't find a solution.

**UPDATE1**: I'm using Windows 8.1 and also tried to start through Kinematic also.

**UPDATE2: Everything worked like charm when I tried Virtualbox Test Build 5.0.3 or later. You can download here: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Testbuilds**

Comment: I'm using Windows 10, virtual box 5.0.8. docker client version 1.8.3 installed via tool box and getting same error.

Comment: I don't think Windows 10 is officially supported yet.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Just run:

```
"C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine" ls
```

get the machine name, and then run:

```
"C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine" env <MACHINE_NAME_HERE> --shell=[cmd|powershell]
```

and you should get something like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine" env default --shell=cmd
set DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
set DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.X.X.X:2376
set DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:\Users\X\.docker\machine\machines\default
set DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=default
# Run this command to configure your shell:
# copy and paste the above values into your command prompt
```

I also get an error `open C:\Users\X\.docker\machine\machines\default\server.pem: The system cannot find the file specified.`
 and solved it by upgrading my VirtualBox to version 5.0.3 (from their [nightly builds](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Testbuilds))

**Long version:**

I got the same problem and after and the "Using Docker from Windows Command Line Prompt (cmd.exe)" section from the [installation manual](https://docs.docker.com/installation/windows/) put me in the right direction

Basically, the way docker works is that the "docker " commands are passed to a docker service (running on port 2375). As you are running the docker from windows host, the service actually runs on the linux host created by docker (you can see it by opening the virtualbox ui).

The usual flow is the following:

1. default machine is created
2. the starter (kinamatic / "Docker Quickstart Terminal" / cmd) of the machine waits for the machine to boot, gets it's IP address and sets the linux ip:port as the service address (instead of 127.0.0.1:2375) in few enviremnt/powershell variables
3. from this point all `docker ...` commands are send to the linux host and everything works almost as native linux

The problem is that there is some issue with the machine setup (my guess the new virtual box but I am not sure and have the time to dig into it). You can see that by runnung the `ls` command and notice that (at least in my case) the state of the machine is "timeout" and there is no url, unlike the output shown in the manual.

This causes the enviorment values not to be set and the `docker ...` commands to fail.

Apart from running the command, you can also start the `Docker Quickstart Terminal` that does the same thing but with sh shell

Regarding the certificate error, I tried to regenrate the certificates from within the virtual machine using:

```
/usr/local/bin/generate_cert --overwrite --host=default,127.0.0.1,10.0.2.15,192.168.99.100 --ca=/var/lib/boot2docker/tls/ca.pem --ca-key=/var/lib/boot2docker/tls/cakey.pem --cert=/var/lib/boot2docker/tls/server.pem --key=/var/lib/boot2docker/tls/serverkey.pem
```

I got "protocol error"s when tried to copy the certificate to the host machine, which reminded me an old virtualbox shared folders bug, so this may not be a problem with docker but with virtualbox -  I upgraded to the latest nightly version (5.0.3-102224), regenerated the default image and that seems to solve it. As windows 10 is not officially supported yet neither by docker nor by virtualbox, I am not sure if this is the same thing that causes you to get the certificate error, In any case can try to copy the certificates from the virtual machine (you have the  paths in code block) to your local user directory (it is mapped to /c/Users/X/ in the virtual machine)

Comment: It reports me the error: `open C:\Users\<my_username>\.docker\machine\machines\default\ca.pem: The system cannot find the file specified.`. And when I cd'ed into the dir, there are no certificates there.

Comment: Seems to be a bug or something: [https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/742](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/742)

Comment: **Update:** I also tried to regenerate the certs using the command `docker-machine regenerate-certs default` but it is stuck forever.

Comment: BTW, I ran into the same problem and what ended up fixing it  was upgrade to virutal box 5.0.3 (nigthly build)

Comment: Hi, thanks for those details, if can help even more here is a resume of what I did : 1) `"C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine" ls`
 2) Install a nighlty build of Virtual Box 3) `docker-machine regenerate-certs default` (before installing a nighlty build Virtual Box this commands never ended) 4) `"C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine" env default --shell=cmd`
 5) Open Docker Terminal and set the variables 6) Close Docker Terminanl an re-open it, now it works ;-)

Comment: @BaptisteGaillard Installed the nightly build of Virtualbox already but I get the `Maximum number of retries (60) exceeded` error.

Comment: @BaptisteGaillard I also get the `ca.pem` error, and `regenerate-certs` hangs for me. But the latest virtual box 5.0.4 is now installed with Docker Toolbox, so that did not help.

Comment: Case it helps too - I had a work box that did not have virtualization enabled and was getting the Error 255.  VirtualBox was able to show me the error so then I had to just fight thru the BIOS and locate the ability to enable it.

Comment: +1000 Seriously, I was so sick of having to cmd with its tiny window, now I can use git bash. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The following worked for me (Docker Toolbox 1.8.1b and Windows 7). It is a simplified version of what @baptiste-gaillard outlined in the comments above.  Short answer: Use VirtualBox 5.03 or later from the get-go.

1. Download VirtualBox 5.03 (nightly build at the time of this post) and extension pack.
2. Reboot laptop. (Clears out running VirtualBox stuff.)
3. Install VirtualBox 5.03 and extension pack 5.03.
4. Delete the default VM entirely (remove files).
5. Re-run Docker Quickstart Terminal shortcut to generate the default VM.

The Quickstart script seems to get along better with VirtualBox 5.03 with regards to creating the requisite TLS keys.

Comment: I can't find version 5.03. The latest version is 5.0.2. Can you refer a link?

Comment: If you prefer not to reboot your machine:
**Step 2 can be skipped/replaced**. 
Installation will block and tell you that some process needs to be kill to continue the installation of VirtualBox, the PID will even be printed in the wizard UI. 
Run `taskkill -f -pid [PID_LISTED]` for all PIDs, and installation should keep going gracefully.

Answer (score 8):

Had the same issue as you showed and Just fixed it a few hours ago.

All need to do is disable Hyper-V. Run a command prompt with **administrator rights** and run the following command:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

Restart your PC, open virtualbox and delete default vm after relaunch, go back to docker quickstart terminal and put the following in command:

```
docker run hello-world
```

and you're done! Hope it solves your problem

Comment: This resolved my issue on Windows 10 after a Windows update turned the hypervisor on

Comment: Enable/Disable Hyper-V on Windows: http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/42041-hyper-v-enable-disable-windows-8-a.html

Answer (score 5):

this works for me

1) start the command line tool first and get the machine ip address by running

**docker-machine ls** command

2) Re-generate certs
docker-machine regenerate-certs

3) Set the evn variables manually in my case the location of certs was different

set DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1

set DOCKER_HOST=tcp://machine_IP:2376

set DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:\Users\X.docker\machine\certs

set DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=default

Now run **docker version**

Here is the output in my case

Client:
 Version:      1.8.1
 API version:  1.20
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   d12ea79
 Built:        Thu Aug 13 02:49:29 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.8.1
 API version:  1.20
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   d12ea79
 Built:        Thu Aug 13 02:49:29 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Answer (score 3):

The Docker Toolbox (in 1.8.x) installation configure by default your Docker Daemon to use secure connection via the TLS protocol (version 1.8).

If you were using an older version of the daemon that wasn't secured that means at least two things : 
 - the port number changed from 2375 to 2376
 - your daemon client need to present a certificat to communicate with you docker engine/server.

So the reply of sandiindia indicates the environment variables that precise to the docker client the good configuration to connect to the docker server/engine:

```
#You're using a TLS secured daemon : 
set DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1

# Precise the Docker Host IP and port, the TLS default is 2376
set DOCKER_HOST=tcp://*<docker_host_IP>*:2376

# The paths to the certificate and client key needed to authenticate to the daemon
# You should have 3 files in this directory : ca.pem, cert.pem and key.pem 
# In my case the default path looks like : 
set DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:\Users\*<username>*\.docker\machine\machines\default

#the name of your Docker Host VM : 
set DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=default
```

The docker documentation about TLS configuration : 
https://docs.docker.com/articles/https/

I hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
Close the virtual machine from Virtual Box (you don't have to delete it)
Close Kitematic
Close Docker Quickstart Terminal
```

Now do this in-order:

```
Open Kitematic
Open Docker Quickstart Terminal
```

Its important **not to** open Docker Quickstart Terminal before Kitematic, as Kitematic will initialize things for Docker Quickstart Terminal

I didn't need to execute any command line..

I hope this will help some body..

Answer (score 2):

I too had the same problem, but I was able to solve it without having to type anything on the command line, it just worked out of the box.

It turns out a few initialization steps were missing, as pointed out in the accepted answer above. Why wasn't the default Docker installation already doing this? I also had missing certs. So, I uninstalled everything and restarted from scratch. However, after the installation completed, this time around **do not open the Docker Quick Start terminal first, open Kitematic instead to do the first initialization for you**.

Kitematic created the certs for me, set the missing env variables and then I opened the Docker Quick Start terminal. I typed `docker run hello-world`, then `docker version` and this time it worked as expected, no error messages.

**Note that this didn't work when I opened the Quick Start terminal first**.

I'm testing Docker inside VMWare 10 instances and I was able to duplicate this problem and its solution (workaround) in every case.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed my issue by simply Removing the default VM in the VirtualBox manager, rebooting PC (just in case), and then re-running Docker Quickstart Terminal. That's it.

Docker 1.8.2 and Virtual Box 5.0.4

Answer (score 1):

1. Update to the latest virtual box above 5.0.3
2. Restart the system
3. open virtual box and remove the default virtual machine
4. open the docker quick start terminal
5. run `docker run hello-world`

And you are done.

Comment: I wake-up this morning, to see the same error again, although it was just perfect three days ago.. I didn't do any thing.. that's strange

Answer (score 1):

Delete and remove all old v.machines on your laptop:
1. Open VirtualBox, right click on 'default', Remove, 'Delete All files'.
2. Command Prompt (Run as Admin)> docker-machine rm default

Uninstall Virtualbox, Docker toolbox and Git.
Navigate to c:\Users\Vinita, and delete dirs.  .docker  and  .Virtualbox
CClean files and registry.
Reboot.

### Cleaning is done.

I. Download latest version of Docker tools for windows (1.10.2) from Docker Toolbox 
Right click on the downloaded file and 'Run as administrator'
This will install - Docker Quickstart, Kitematic and Virtualbox.

II. Download latest test build of VirtualBox (5.01.15-105696-win.exe) from
Testbuilds – Oracle VM VirtualBox . Run as Administrator again.

### (You can ignore any warnings and overwrite on the already Docker-installed VirtualBox).

So far, Nothing out of the ordinary. We just  installed the software with Admin rights.
Now, Control Panel>Network and Sharing Center>Change adapter settings:
Right click VirtualBox Host-Only Network #2 for Properties.
**Check> VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Networking Driver.**
(If it is already checked, uncheck and check again.)

You are done. This is the only fix that we have employed!

Both Kitematic and Docker Quickstart should work now.

Right click on Kitematic and Run as admin the first time. 
Tested on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered exactly the same error when I run **docker images** after a system reboot. I used docker version 1.10 on Windows 7 64 bits with virtualbox 5.0.10 and mintty(the terminal come with Git for Windows)

Executing **docker-machine ls** showed me the virtual machine is in Timeout state.

`$ docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL   SWARM   DOCKER   ERRORS
default            virtualbox   Timeout`

So I restarted the virtual machine

`$ docker-machine restart default`

Then list the status again told me the cert is bound to an incorrect address:

`$ docker-machine ls
Unable to query docker version: Get https://192.168.56.101:2376/v1.15/version: x509: certificate is valid for 192.168.99.101, not 192.168.56.101`

Then I regenerate the cert

`$ docker-machine regenerate-certs default`

and finally

`$ eval $(docker-machine env default --shell=bash)`

Then docker is working again!

Answer (score 1):

With Docker 1.8.1d had the same problem, having uninstalled 1.8.1c. Eventually fixed problem by installing latest Virtual Box (5.0.18), rebooting when prompted and starting Kitematic. Kitematic fails at first and offers option to remove and re-install the VM which I did. After that my QuickStart Terminal was OK.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the problem with virtual box, 
 In my case, I have performed below steps to resolve the issue

- Stop Docker machine by 'docker-machine stop'
- Open Network and sharing Center in Windows OS
- Click on Change Adapter settings
- Disable the VirtualBox-Host Only Network
- Start Docker machine by 'docker-machine start'

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Docker Toolbox on Windows 10 Home. The steps to fix the problem from [here](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2596#issuecomment-420619675):

1. run `docker-machine ls` to get a list, you should probably see this:

```
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL   SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
default   -        virtualbox   Stopped                 Unknown
```

2. Optional step upgrading (be patient):

```
docker-machine upgrade
```

3. restart the `default`:

```
docker-machine start default
```

don't worry if says:

> Machine "default" is already running.

4. now you should be able to run `docker version` and see something like:

```
Client:
 Version:           19.03.1
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.7
 Git commit:        74b1e89e8a
 Built:             Wed Jul 31 15:18:18 2019
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.5
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.12
  Git commit:       633a0ea838
  Built:            Wed Nov 13 07:28:45 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.2.10
  GitCommit:        b34a5c8af56e510852c35414db4c1f4fa6172339
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc8+dev
  GitCommit:        3e425f80a8c931f88e6d94a8c831b9d5aa481657
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

Answer (score 0):

This has happened a few times for me on Windows 10 with VirtualBox 5.0.14.

It seems to be related with not shutting down VirtualBox correctly (I believe) - for example, a power cut!

1. Shutdown the Docker VM
2. Close Kitematic
3. Start the Docker Quickstart Terminal
4. Type in the terminal:

> docker-machine.exe -D ls

5. Start Kitematic. VM's show up now.

If that does not work, try 1-3 again and this time try to regenerate
certs. Then do step 4.

One thing that is odd, is that in the terminal `docker images` does not list them but says it cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:2375 (but `docker-machine ls` shows the default machine running on 192.168.99.100:2376).

Answer (score 0):

Just recreate the default machine, and then run

```
docker-machine env default
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using docker for windows(beta) follow this steps:

- Disable the "DockerNAT" network adapter
- Run the "Reset to factory defaults" via the taskbar / docker / settings / Reset to factory defaults"

Answer (score 0):

On my non-virtual machine, I got same error. Below steps worked for me

Right click docker->Under Settings->General do you have Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS enabled? You need to if you want to access the daemon as described. But please do keep in mind that this setting is insecure as explained in the warning.

Answer (score -2):

My issue was "...error getting IP address" Thanks to all the people here who have contributed their solutions which I read through and performed these steps:

1. Close Docker
2. Open VirtualBox Manager
3. Delete default VM
4. Start Kitematic first (I think this is important)
5. Start Docker