# Docker: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: docker

[ErrorDisplayedHere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fe1lz.png)
I tried many ways like reinstalling Docker, changing DNS server,restarting windows, but nothing worked out.

> Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally docker: Error
>   response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp
>   100.24.246.89:443: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker says: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37234194/docker-says-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-ref)

Answer (score 1):

Open Docker Settings and select "Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS" (on the General tab), then apply & restart Docker.  Do note the warning about the vulnerability that this option exposes.

Comment: I had to restart my machine to get this to work