# Docker Windows dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2376: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: docker, windows-10

I just installed Docker Desktop on Windows 10 and while running the command `docker run hello-world`, I keep getting the error "dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2376: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

Any solution to this problem, From other stackoverflow answers, I deleted the DOCKER_* env variables, but it did not solve the problem.

I even selected "Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS" option as told by the answer in this link: [Docker: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60716836/docker-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused)

There were some solutions involving `docker-machine` command (see the [link](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3501)), but the windows powershell cannot find the command.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the options under the Troubleshoot menu to solve this issue. This helps me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove DOCKER_TLS as well as DOCKER_HOST environment variables.  Have your docker desktop running.

Then try executing:
docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started

It should work.