# How to use docker --host (error during connect)

Tags: docker

Trying to run the command on Windows with docker desktop:

`docker -H tcp://127.0.0.1:2376 ps`

returns `error during connect: Get "http://127.0.0.1:2376/v1.24/containers/json": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2376: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

I have followed [this advice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/configure-docker-daemon) by adding the below in `C:\ProgramData\Docker\config\daemon.json`

```
{
    "hosts": ["tcp://0.0.0.0:2375","tcp://127.0.0.1:2376"]
}
```

With still the same error.

Note: `set | grep DOCKER` returns nothing. seems like no envvars are present.

Note2: regular docker commands work fine.

Comment: You should almost never need the `docker -H` option, and trying to configure TCP access to the Docker daemon can lead to a massive critical security exposure if you don't do it perfectly.  Why are you trying to add this option?

Comment: because I'm using pulumi which needs it for networks

Comment: specifically: https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/docker/ (typescript version)

Comment: So more specifically, making `$DOCKER_HOST` available like that is literally equivalent to disabling your root password – it allows any local process to take over the entire host.  If you set the Docker daemon to be visible on 0.0.0.0 then anyone who can reach your system over the network can root it.

Comment: Pulumi doesn't need this for networks, at all. What is your desired goal?

Comment: ok. my goal is to follow this link, for which I apparently (as per the pulumi documentation) need to allow tcp access to 2376. pulumi.com/registry/packages/docker

Comment: @DavidMaze I understand, and won't keep it forever, but I'd like to have a working procedure should I ever need it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

1. Right-click on your PC
2. Properties
3. Advanced system settings
4. Environment Variables
5. Add new Variable: DOCKER_HOST ;
   Value: tcp://127.0.0.1:2375
6. Run Docker Desktop
7. bottom-right, right-click on Docker-Desktop
8. Settings
9. Enable the following option: "Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375
   without TLS"

[Docker says: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37234194/docker-says-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-ref)

Comment: thanks. Only the `Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS` option works for now. is there any way to use port 2376 with TLS? adding the `DOCKER-HOST` envvar doesn't work