# Docker not working in Windows10

Tags: windows, docker, docker-machine

I am using `Docker version 1.12.2, build bb80604` and `VirtualBox 5.1.6`.

I was able to install `Docker Toolbox` correctly but I am not able to start the default VM.

I tried to follow the instruction given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32047660/docker-for-windows-not-working) but I am still getting `The system cannot find the file specified` error. I don't have `Hyper-V` enabled on system.

```
F:\>docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER      STATE   URL   SWARM   DOCKER   ERRORS
default            not found   Error                          open C:\Users\Animesh\.docker\machine\machines\default\config.json: The system cannot find the file specified.

F:\>docker-machine env --shell=cmd
open C:\Users\Animesh\.docker\machine\machines\default\config.json: The system cannot find the file specified.

F:\>docker rm default
An error occurred trying to connect: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: first question is: does that file actually exist?

Comment: I does not. I added an empty `config.json` myself and it threw this error `Error getting migrated host: unexpected end of JSON input`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like something bad happened to your docker-machine default machine.

To recover, do the following:

```
docker-machine rm -f default
```

Next, open the virtualbox GUI and make sure that there isn't a VM that corresponds with that old "default" VM, just in case. If there is, manually delete it from there.

Now, open the quickstart terminal again and it should create a new "default" virtual machine for you.

Alternatively, you can create it like this:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-memory 2048 default
```

At that point, your sequence of commands should work as expected again.

Comment: I wish that worked for me I got About to remove default
WARNING: This action will delete both local reference and remote instance.   "Can't remove default".

Comment: That would suggest that there's something still using the VM or that the virtualbox command to delete didn't complete successfully for some reason.  rerun the delete command in debug mode and see if it gives you more info: `docker-machine --debug rm -f default`

Comment: The missing config file blocks it regardless not sure why.  But for now I will have to create a new one.

Comment: Thanks, this got me up and running.  Can we rename the Virtual Box from "default" to "Docker".  If we have several VMs, then it is not clear which one is Docker.  I tried that, and I think that is maybe what caused my problem; but my compute also rebooted today, so not sure.

Comment: @NealWalters The name 'default' has a special meaning in docker-machine-- you can omit a name and it will act as though you used 'default'. If you opt to use a different name, then you can simply always specify it on the command line. If you use the quickstart terminal or kitematic, those will always try to use the "default" machine and create it if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Having docker inside VirtualBox and executing this command, it changed my internal docker virtualbox ip from 192.168.99.100 to 192.168.99.101 btw

Comment: Now I'm getting a different error:
.DriverName,Docker machine "default" already exists,

Comment: @olNoy I think it happened to me too a few times because Toolbox was already running but with administrative rights, so also client must be run as administrative or toolbox must be run as a standard user

Answer (score 5):

You may need another couple of steps additional to what @programmerq mentioned.

- Create empty text file: `C:\Users\<user>\.docker\machine\machines\default\config.json`
- Stop `VBoxHeadless.exe` service from Windows task manager

Try `docker-machine rm -f default` and `docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-memory 2048 default` commands afterwards to remove/add *default*

Answer (score 0):

step 1: run:  `docker-machine rm -f default` - (on your mac terminal or control panel)

step 2: run:  `docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-memory 2048 default`

It worked like miracle.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a Windows Home user, you will not be able install the Docker for Windows Desktop edition, as it requires Hyper-V virtualization. This is supported only by Windows Professional and Enterprise editions.

As the Docker for Windows Desktop edition requires Hyper-V virtualization, you will not be able to install it if you are a Windows Home user. It is only supported by Windows Professional and Enterprise editions.

If you have installed `Docker Toolbox` and you are dealing with errors while trying to start the default machine you can create a new one by running:

```
docker-machine create box
```

the in order to see how to connect your Docker Client to the Docker Engine running on the virtual machine created run:

```
docker-machine env box
```

the command that you need to run in order to configure your shell will then appear:

```
eval $("C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe" env box)
```

Check that the installation is runnung correctly by running:

```
docker run hello-world
```

Then you just need to start your machine every time you need to use docker:

```
docker-machine start box
```

and follow the second and third steps above for the configuration.