# Docker Desktop installation on windows 7 is not working

Tags: windows, docker, installation, windows-7, docker-desktop

I've downloaded docker desktop from the website but was unable to open the installer.
My operating system is windows 7.
What are the steps required to install docker desktop on windows 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docker Desktop is not supported on windows 7, you can use Docker toolbox instead.
Do following steps:

- Install [hyper-v](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mn5wDnknxho)
- Install Docker Toolbox and try to follow [link instructions](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/)
- Run Docker Quickstart as admin.

After following above steps, you may not be able to run **Docker Quickstart Terminal** properly. If so, follow below steps:

- Go to window's Start.
- type: *Environment*
- click: *Edit the system environment variables*
- Make sure you have *VBOX_INSTALL_PATH* (should point to VirtualBox installation folder. i.e. *C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox*)
- Make sure you have *VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH* (should point to VirtualBox installation folder. i.e. *C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox*)
- Make sure you have *VBOX_USER_HOME* (e.g. *C:\Users\Sara.VirtualBox*)
- Make sure you have *DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALL_PATH* in your User variables (i.e. *C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox*)
- Restart your computer.

Try Running **Kitematic**. If its not working and you are receiving an error about "default" already existing or config.json missing, do the following:

- close Docker Quickstart Terminal if open.
- open task *manager -> processes*.
- End process **VBoxHeadless.exe**
- add an empty config.json file manually in *%userprofile%.docker\machine\machines\default* if **config.json** is missing.
- Run in CMD: *docker-machine rm -f default*
- Run in CMD: *docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-memory 2048 default*

If the above CMD commands failed:

- delete folder *%userprofile%.docker\machine\machines\default* manually
- restart computer
- run Docker Quickstart Terminal as admin
- folder *%userprofile%.docker\machine\machines\default* should have been created properly at this point.
- open kitematic. UI should be presented properly

---

[Problem with "default" project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53937359/4884749)

[Failure on "default"](https://imgs.developpaper.com/imgs/2261466744-5661af1891e88_articlex.png)

Comment: The link points to installation of Docker Desktop instead of Docker Toolbox

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Docker desktop require Windows 10.

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/

> System Requirements
>
> Windows 10 64-bit: Pro, Enterprise, or Education (Build 15063 or later).

Answer (score 0):

You will need Win10 pro to install Docker on PC, but otherwise you can still install Docker on PC by downloading Docker Toolbox for Win7,8,10. Link to download Docker Toolbox at:

[https://www.softpedia.com /get/Programming/Other-Programming-Files/Docker-Toolbox.shtml](http://You%20will%20need%20Win10%20pro%20to%20install%20Docker%20on%20PC,%20but%20otherwise%20you%20can%20still%20install%20Docker%20on%20PC%20by%20downloading%20Docker%20Toolbox%20for%20Win7,8,10.%20Link%20to%20download%20Docker%20Toolbox%20at%20https://www.softpedia.com%20/get/Programming/Other-Programming-Files/Docker-Toolbox.shtml)