# issue in Downloading Platform-specific Binaries

Tags: binary, hyperledger-fabric, ibm-blockchain

I want to download Binary files for running Hyperledger Fabric. I am trying to execute this command. I am behind proxy too. 
Also I have docker Installed, OS being used Win 10.

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://172.16.30.30:80/
export HTTPS_PROXY=https://172.16.30.30:8080/
export NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,::1

$ curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s 1.1.0 1.1.0 0.4.6

Installing hyperledger/fabric-samples repo

===> Checking out v1.1.0 of hyperledger/fabric-samples
HEAD is now at 1252c7a... [FAB-8920] Pin fabric-samples to node.js "~1.1.0"

Installing Hyperledger Fabric binaries

===> Downloading version x86_64-1.1.0 platform specific fabric binaries
===> Downloading:  https://nexus.hyperledger.org/content/repositories/releases/org/hyperledger/fabric/hyperledger-fabric/windows-amd64-1.1.0/hyperledger-fabric-windows-amd64-1.1.0.tar.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 28.0M  100 28.0M    0     0  91407      0  0:05:21  0:05:21 --:--:--  145k
```

... Here 2 files are downloaded and Then i get this erros continiously

```
Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon (error during connect: Get https://127.0.0.1:2376/v1.37/info: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2376: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.). Using system default: https://index.docker.io/v1/
error during connect: Post https://127.0.0.1:2376/v1.37/images/create?fromImage=hyperledger%2Ffabric-peer&tag=x86_64-1.1.0: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2376: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
error during connect: Post https://127.0.0.1:2376/v1.37/images/hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.1.0/tag?repo=hyperledger%2Ffabric-peer&tag=latest: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2376: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
==> FABRIC IMAGE: orderer
===> List out hyperledger docker images
error during connect: Get https://127.0.0.1:2376/v1.37/images/json: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2376: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

Comment: your docker daemon is not properly set up, see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32047660/docker-for-windows-not-working/32059408#32059408)

Comment: it was a netowrk issue and yes your link helped me a lot thanks